# Image of a subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ is open

Tags: normed-spaces

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ be continuously differentiable. Suppose $f'(0)$ has non-zero determinant. Let $U = \left\{x \in \Bbb{R}^2 : ||f'(x)-f'(0)||<\frac{1}{2||f'(0)||}\right\}$. Show that $f(U)$ is open.

I have tried doing this using generic properties of a norm but that didn't work. I suspect that I'll need to specifically use what the norm is. And I don't know what that is. The wikipedia article on norms for matrices didn't help.

So an answer telling what the norm is( in this case for a $2\times2$ matrix) and the general direction to proceed in would be helpful.

Comment: Do you really want $\frac{1}{2\Vert f'(0) \Vert}$? Or do you mean $\frac{\Vert f'(0) \Vert}{2}$?

Comment: No, I wrote the question right. I'm not sure if it matters though, maybe you can just replace the right side of the inequality with any positive real number and it would be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $f(x,y)=\left(\left(x-\frac14\right)^2,\left(y-\frac14\right)^2\right)$. Then $f'\left(0,0\right)=-\frac12\operatorname{Id}$ and so $\left\|f'\left(0,0\right)\right\|=\frac12$. On the other hand, $f'\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)=0$ and so $\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)\in U$. But then $f(U)$ is not open, since $(0,0)=f\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)\in U$ but both coordinates of any element of $f(U)$ is greater than or equal to $0$.

Comment: I'm not sure how your last line implies that $f(U)$ is not open. Could you clarify

Comment: The point $(0,0)$ is in $U$, but no ball centered around it is contained in $U$.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it. Thanks

Comment: Btw, you meant to say that $(0,0) = f(1/4,1/4) \in f(U)$, I think.

Comment: @Guy Indeed, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is in general not true. Take

$$ f_c: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \ f_c(x,y)=\left(\sin \left(\frac{x}{c}\right), \sin\left(\frac{y}{c}\right)\right).$$

One computes

$$ f_c'(x,y)= \frac{1}{c}\begin{pmatrix} \cos\left(\frac{x}{c}\right) & 0 \\ 0 & \cos\left(\frac{y}{c} \right) \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{c} f_1'\left( \frac{x}{c}, \frac{y}{c} \right).$$

We have

$$ \Vert f_c'(0,0) - f_c'(x,y) \Vert 
\leq 2 \max_{(u,v)\in [0, 2\pi c]\times [0,2\pi c]} \Vert f_c'(u,v) \Vert 
= \frac{2}{c} \max_{(u,v)\in [0, 2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]} \Vert f_1'(u,v) \Vert.$$

Thus, if we choose $c>0$ such that $ c^2> 2 \Vert f_1'(0,0) \Vert \cdot \max_{(u,v)\in [0, 2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]} \Vert f_1'(u,v) \Vert $, then

$$ U= \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \ \Vert f_c'(x,y) - f_c'(0,0) \Vert < \frac{1}{2\Vert f'(0,0) \Vert} \} = \mathbb{R}^2.$$

However,

$$ f_c(\mathbb{R}^2)=f_c([0, 2\pi c]\times [0, 2\pi c]) = [-1,1]\times [-1,1],$$

which is not open.